# Target minSdkVersion api level 16 and targetSdkVersion api level 22

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the minimum SDK version in Android Studio from API 23 to API 16.and build target verion to 22.
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
 //        versionCode 1
//        versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
 }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile files('libs/classes.jar')
}
//task to delete the old jar
 task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
 }

  //task to export contents as jar
 task exportJar(type: Copy) {
  from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
into('release/')
include('classes.jar')
///Rename the jar
rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
 }

 exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

I can't find any Design library for this :
com.android.support:design:23.1.0
so as a result i my 
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior')
and
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.votel.gpslocation'
and i attach a screen shot

Comment: Did you download Android Support Library in the SDK manager ? What's its version ?

Comment: Yes its Android Support Library 23.1.1

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using compileSdkVersion = 22, you should use a design support library that is version 22.x e.g. com.android.support:design:22.2.0 or com.android.support:design:22.2.1

Comment: I just curious to know how to figure this out that if the compileSdkVersion 22 Then what is the build tool version.
And what is the app compat and design tool version
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: Your support library version must be of the same major version as the compileSdkVersion. If your compileSdkVersion will be changed to 23, the support version must be 23.x.x

Comment: Here's a good article about versions: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd